Convert epub folder to epub file
I have a large collection of epub books. I’m trying to make a few changes using a package called Magic (derived from Sigil), but I’ve discovered that it won’t open some books.
It seems that some of the epubs are actually folders, and neither Magic nor Sigil likes that.
If I zip the folder and rename it to .epub, it works, so I can do the following:

zip the folder test.epub to test.zip
delete the test.epub folder
rename the test.zip file to test.zip

It works, but I wonder whether there’s a utility which will do that for me?

Not an answer but how were those folders created they are not epub books. This is a very unusual setup so I doubt there is any tool for this.

A true EPUB file is a zipped archive, containing multiple components, as shown below:

Whatever application created the folder had not yet zipped it. That seems a bit odd, since modern devices can handle zip archives very rapidly, but, as you discovered, those folders can easily be zipped.
Many other modern document file types are similar zipped archives, such as MS Word's DOCX, LibreOffice Calc's ODS and Impress's ODP, etc.
